# Rails API with devise, can't run POST #create method with JSON call from client

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, devise

So I'm trying to create a Rails API with devise. My client side works well with GET, but I can't do POST type of calls. If I try to create a user I keep getting the following devise html form as response.

```html
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<form class="new_user" id="new_user" action="/users" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="RGZxLuXcOCbxKVdpFc/wSAKEp3wcxqpfnvmv0nstEcOppPyViWcmdu+dPt84XQeSkCmwRg0REZN+vTdX1j+MOQ==" />
      <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2>2 errors prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>
      <ul><li>Email can&#39;t be blank</li><li>Password can&#39;t be blank</li></ul>
    </div>


  <div class="field">
    <div class="field_with_errors"><label for="user_email">Email</label></div><br />
    <div class="field_with_errors"><input autofocus="autofocus" type="email" name="user[email]" id="user_email" /></div>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <div class="field_with_errors"><label for="user_password">Password</label></div>
    <em>(4 characters minimum)</em>
    <br />
    <div class="field_with_errors"><input autocomplete="off" type="password" name="user[password]" id="user_password" /></div>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <label for="user_password_confirmation">Password confirmation</label><br />
    <input autocomplete="off" type="password" name="user[password_confirmation]" id="user_password_confirmation" />
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Sign up" />
  </div>
</form>
  <a href="/users/sign_in">Log in</a><br />



  <a href="/users/confirmation/new">Didn&#39;t receive confirmation instructions?</a><br />
```

Interestingly, at first I would get a *"Can't verify CSRF token authenticity"* error, so I added *beforeSend* to my JSON call. This would than change my call to OPTIONS, even though it was specified as a POST.

My call:

```js
$(document).on('page:change', function(){
  $('body').on('submit', 'form.create_new_user', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var user_data = $(this).serializeJSON();
    $.ajax({
      url: Host.address + '/users',
      beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'))},
      type: 'post',
      datatype:'json',
      data: {info: {full_name: user_data.full_name,
                    email: user_data.email,
                    password: user_data.password,
                    password_confirmation: user_data.password_confirmation}}
    }).done(function(response){
      console.log(response)
      if (response.success.success) {
        logInGoToWithNotice(response, '/', 'Thank you for signig up');
      } else{
        alert("User wasn't created. Please try again.")
      };
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And API does this:

```
Started OPTIONS "/users" for ::1 at 2015-09-30 14:09:49 +0200

ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant RegistrationsController):
...
```

If I now remove *beforeSend*, I'd get the form again, just that *"Can't verify CSRF token authenticity"* error wouldn't be there anymore, but instead I'd get successful POST, that still returns html form.

```
Started POST "/users" for ::1 at 2015-09-30 14:25:57 +0200  

Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as */*
Parameters: {"info"=>{"full_name"=>"User Admin", "email"=>"user.admin@email.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
  (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
Rendered /Users/antonpot/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/devise-3.5.2/app/views/devise/shared/_links.html.erb (0.2ms)
Rendered /Users/antonpot/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/devise-3.5.2/app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb (3.5ms)  
Completed 200 OK in 9ms (Views: 4.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
```

Now if I look into my Users Controller I can see I'm never even running my #create, as it never prints `p "C"*99`

```rb
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def create
    p "C"*99
    user = User.new
    user.full_name = user_params[:full_name]
    user.email = user_params[:email].downcase
    user.password = user_params[:password]
    user.password_confirmation = user_params[:password_confirmation]
    if user.save
      render json: {success:{success: true, user_id: user.id, errorMessage: nil, errorNumber: 201}}
    else
      render json: {success:{success: false, errorMessage: user.errors.messages.to_s, errorNumber: 400}}
    end
  end
end
```

Why can't I call it? What do I need to do for this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First**

This issue because of cross-site-scripting problem. The `client url` is different than the `api url`. The `HTTP method OPTIONS`, is a **pre-flight** request that the browser makes to determine whether a cross-domain `AJAX` request should be allowed.

if cross-domain `AJAX` request is allowed the `POST` which is the actual request will be sent.

So you need to allow cross-domain `AJAX` request on your server.

**Second**

Make sure your `routes.rb` is set correctly.

You need to configure your devise and instruct him to use your `customized registration_controller` instead of `default devise registration controller`

adjust `devise_for :users` in your `routes.rb` to be something like the following:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "users/registrations"}
```

assuming that the `customized registration class` exist in the `users` folder

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Routing fixes the issue and it works great, but I do have a sub-question. If I call without headers, all is fine, but if I do use headers, as you suggested, I get a Routing error, because it looks for a POST route on my client side, not on server side. Why wouldn't it call specified url?

Comment: @antonpot, you can ignore the third part of my answer, the `csrf token` needed if we are talking about post request within the same domain but the situation here is different. the `the csrf token` is generated on the client side doesnt related by all means to your server